# No module named scrapy_splash

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am on OSX:

I installed scrapy-splash using `pip install scrapy splash` and that went well

I add this code block to my spider

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

Then when I try to run my spider, I get this error message:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/scrapy", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())


  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/lowesSpider/lowesSpider/spiders/lowes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_splash'
```

Honestly I'm not too sure where to go from here so any help would be appreciated and let me know if there's any clarification needed!

Comment: I had a similar issue just yesterday. I was recommended to use `python -m pip install packagename` instead of just `pip` to make sure it is installed with the right python environment.

Comment: @Harri thanks for the recommendation but I get 'Requirement already satisfied: scrapy_splash in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.7.2)' when running that

Comment: the error message says the python version is 3.8, so check to make sure it's installed for this version.

Comment: @Matts how would I check where it is installed for

Answer (score 1):

I was making the same mistake: it is *scrapy-splash*, not **scrapy_splash**.